# How to change the numbering style in list of table and list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a thesis and I want to change the numbering style in list of table and list of figures from "1.1 to Fig 1.1" and from "1.1 to Table 1.1" as shown below.

List of Figures

Fig. 1,1: This is figure vvvvv
         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Fig. 2,1: This is figure blah blah
Fig. 3,1: This is figure blah blah

List of Tables

Table 1,1: This is figure blah blah
Table 1,3: This is figure blah blah
Table 4,1: This is figure blah blah

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX aSX! You can take a look at the  `tocloft` package, in particular the `\cftXpresnum` and ` cftXnumwidth` commands described p.9 of the documentation. Another useful package is `titletoc`, which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: Alternatively, modify \l@figure and \l@table from your document class.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing. For instance you say you want to change numbering in the LoF from "1.1" to "Fig 1.1" but later you show your expected result as "Fig. 1,1:". You don't say what class you are using but assuming it might be `report` (or any other reasonable class for a thesis) then you can use the `tocloft` package like below to change the figure numbering from "1.1" etc. to "Fig 1.1:" etc.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% for figures
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Fig. } % put before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{: }  % put after the number
% adjust spacing
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}
% and similarly for tables
```

Read the `tocloft` manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) for details of what the above `\cft...` macros do.

Changing the figure/table numbering from "1.1" to "1,1" as in your example is a completely different question, as is your exampled desire not to have unnecessary line breaks between the LoF/LoT entries.